# Getting objects (maximum) diamater in eCognition?

Tags: ecognition

i'm trying to model some tree crowns in in eCognition Developer 9. I already do have some objects which are more or less of a circular shape but slightly irregular (because of overlapping in the canopy).

Is there a way to calculate the maximum (based on on the "largest extent") diameters of each of these objects?

Because i think it would be closer to the real diameter which is why i'm not simply using the area attribute for calculation.

Comment: Are you committed to staying within eCognition, or are you willing to use ArcGIS to find the polygon diameter?

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I thought about using the Minimum Bounding Geometry tool in ArcGIS (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003q000000) as well. But finding the maximum diameter in eCognition would save a lot of im- and exporting. Plus i could use it in my classification process, so i would prefer staying with eCognition if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I will be staying tuned as I also have been looking for a way to do this entirely in eCognition.

Comment: What is wrong with the 'Width' and 'Length' parameters in eCog?